# High potential between ground and neutral wires in wall outlet

Tags: power-electronics, mains

I would like to test if ground connection works properly in my wall outlet. To do so, I have tried to measure voltage across ground and neutral wires. And here comes the interesting part:

U(Live, Neutral) = 198V (220 +/- 10% V AC, fine)
U(Neutral, Ground) = 89 V (What?)
U(Live, Ground) = 108 V (what?)

Yes, I know it's not *correct* way to test it, but at least this method should give general idea if ground works or not. In reality, resistance should also be measured.

But how can it happen that I observe such voltage ratings?

Comment: The PE wire is probably floating, not connected.

Comment: But if PE is floating (meaning no ground), then U(Live, Geound) should be equal to U(Live, Neutral). How come some of the voltage is dropped? Leakage?

Comment: Recommend getting an [electrical outlet tester](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=electrical+outlet+tester&iax=shopping&ia=shopping). Good idea to check all of the outlets.

Comment: It picks up like an antenna, the voltage is induced due to the current flow in surrounding wires.

Comment: Definitely a good idea to get a plug tester.  You're on the wrong stack too.  This is more of a DIY than an EE question I think.  This could be an open neutral problem.  If that's the case a plug tester will tell you.  Can be caused by a broken wire, bad splice or failed termination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a ground fault and thus no ground which is defined by 0 V.

Neutral should be earth grounded outside at your distribution transformer and your voltage drop permitted is 10% of line on neutral if drawing maximum current in your location. (e.g. 100 or 200A)

Check at breaker box and move towards the problem (inside or out) to get it fixed otherwise if you happen to touch an appliance like a 3 pronged device AND the plumbing which ought to be earth grounded, you will see a potential risk voltage but it MAY be high impedance floating so lower current depending on the cable capacitance.

Comment: indeed, faulty ground...